# Sum of rows and column in a Matrix

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

the problem arises when I use a different number of rows and columns, for example, 2 by 3 otherwise, it is running okay. the sum of column outputs garbage values
I can't seem to understand where the bug is.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <conio.h>
    using namespace std;
    int main ()
    {
    int a[10][10];
    int i,row,column, j, s = 0, sum = 0;
    cout<<"Enter Number of rows: ";
    cin>>row;
    cout<<"Enter Number of columns: ";
    cin>>column;
    cout<< "Enter elements Matrix \n";
    for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < column; j++)
            cin >> a[i][j];

    cout << "Matrix Entered By you is \n";
    for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j <column; j++)
            cout << a[i][j] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j <column; j++)
            s = s + a[i][j];
        cout << "Sum of Row " << i + 1 << " is: " << s;
        s = 0;
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
    for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < column; j++)
            s = s + a[j][i];
        cout << "Sum of Column " << i + 1 << " is: " << s;
        s = 0;
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd start with the lack of `main`. Remember every change we have tio make to your code to get it compiling is an opportunity for us to accidentally insert or fix a bug.

Comment: It won't work when `row != column` because you're swapping i and j (row/column) ie., `a[i][j]` becomes `a[j][i]` .
You want to keep `a[i][j]` at all times, and swap the two `for`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not iterating correctly to get your columns sum, `column` and `row` are switched up. change to:

```
for (i = 0; i < column; i++) // <-----
{
    for (j = 0; j < row; j++) // <-----
        s = s + a[j][i];
    cout << "Sum of Column " << i + 1 << " is: " << s;
    s = 0;
    cout << endl;
}
```

Consider a 3x4 matrix:

```
1 2 3 4 
1 2 3 4 
1 2 3 4
```

Your current loop would access it in the following manner, invoking undefined behavior.

```
[1] [2] [3] 4
[1] [2] [3] 4
[1] [2] [3] 4 
[?] [?] [?]
```